# How can I ensure a longer life for uninstalled batteries?

Tags: battery, battery-life

I picked up a few HP TouchPads for me and the family over the weekend, but I want to be prepared for the future.  I would like to buy a couple of batteries now so that I can replace them myself when they inevitably fail in a few years.

1. How can I make sure those batteries stay viable when they aren't being used?
2. Is this even possible?
3. Should I just wait until a year or so when they look like they are going out and hope that I can still buy a replacement?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HP Touchpads use a liquid polymer battery.  They can be stored, follow these [instructions](http://www.rctoys.com/pr/2007/09/25/lithium-polymer-battery-winter-storage-lipo-care-lipoly/) for best life.

Answer (score 2):

In general, leave the battery at least partly charged, wrap it in air-tight plastic, and store it in a refrigerator.  This is reasonably good for most battery types.

(Partially) recharge the battery every 6/12 months.

The old nicads preferred to be stored discharged, though.

Storing in a freezer is good for some types but may damage others.

(When buying replacement batteries make sure you're getting new/new stock, not new/old stock that has been sitting on a (hot) warehouse shelf for years.  Often it's better to buy a 3rd-party brand than to buy the OEM version for this reason.)

Answer (score 1):

I am with the view that it is better to buy only when you have a need for it.  And get original or OEM from official supplier so that one can get proper warranty.  We buy battery for the use, that means getting the reasonable capacity expected of it.